# Convert String to Int to subtract from another number. Python

Tags: python

I'm really not even sure about if I've worded the title correctly. Essentially I'm supposed to take a list of five products and prices, sort them in order from most to least expensive. Then take the cheapest price and subtract it from the total overall price.

I've been able to do everything except this final step. I can find the cheapest price, and the total price. I just can't subtract one from the other without an error.

Here's my code:

```
totalprice = (0)
allproducts = {}


for i in range (5):
    products = input("Enter product name")
    prices = float(input("Enter a product price"))
    allproducts[products]=prices
    totalprice = prices + totalprice


lowestprice = min(allproducts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])


sortedprice = sorted(allproducts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)

sortedprice.reverse()

fulltotal = totalprice - lowestprice


print("Your Items From Most to Least Expensive:", sortedprice)
print("Cheapest Item:", lowestprice)
print("Your Total Before Discount is:", totalprice)

print("Your Price With Discount is:", fulltotal)
```

Now if I run this code without the "fulltotal = totalprice - lowestprice, and "Print(fulltotal)", everything works fine. However when I add them, I get this in my output:

```
Enter product nameProduct 1
Enter a product price15
Enter product nameProduct 2
Enter a product price20
Enter product nameProduct 3
Enter a product price10
Enter product nameProduct 4
Enter a product price25
Enter product nameProduct 5
Enter a product price5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatel\Documents\Assessment2.py", line 19, in <module>
    fulltotal = totalprice - lowestprice
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `lowestprice` is a (key, value) tuple.

The reason is that `items()` is designed to iterate through the (key, value) tuples of the dictionary. This is the same reason you needed to use `key=lambda x: x[1]` to get at the `value` within each `(key, value)` tuple yielded by `items()` in `min()` and `sorted()`.

Accessing index 1 of the tuple returned by `min()` would fix your code:

```py
lowestprice = min(allproducts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
```

However, a more streamlined approach might be to use `values()` instead of `items()` throughout your example:

```py
lowestprice = min(allproducts.values())
sortedprice = sorted(allproducts.values(), reverse=True)
fulltotal = totalprice - lowestprice
```

The `values()` method lets you iterate over value only (no key), which seems to be what's really relevant in your case.

---

Here's an overview of `items()`, `values()` and `keys()` which are known as "dictionary view objects": https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

Comment: @Princey Do you need any more help with your question? Please consider marking one of the answers as "accepted" if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had an issue with the type of `lowestprice`
When I ran the code it appeared that its type was a tuple. Therefore it can't be substracted with the total price.

Try and run with this line instead :

```py
lowestprice = min(allproducts.values())
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

`lowestprice = min(allproducts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])` is returning a tuple `(product_name, product_price)`. `lowestprice = min(allproducts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[1]` will return just the price and then everything works.

Comment: I get this error:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lowestprice'

Answer (score 0):

Your lowestprice was a tuple, not a string or float. Here, I have picked the 1st element from the tuple, which is the lowest price.

```
totalprice = 0
allproducts = {}


for i in range (5):
    products = input("Enter product name")
    prices = float(input("Enter a product price"))
    allproducts[products]=prices
    totalprice = prices + totalprice


lowestprice = min(allproducts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[1] #Added [1]


sortedprice = sorted(allproducts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)

sortedprice.reverse()

fulltotal = totalprice - lowestprice


print("Your Items From Most to Least Expensive:", sortedprice)
print("Cheapest Item:", lowestprice)
print("Your Total Before Discount is:", totalprice)

print("Your Price With Discount is:", fulltotal)
```

Comment: This worked! Great solution

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked to benefit others.